# I set the deployment target to iOS8 and App store says "Compatibility: Requires iOS 7.0 or later". Can I force app to install only in iOS8 only?

Tags: ios, ios8, deployment-target

I released an iOS 8 version of my app today and wanted to limit it only to users running iOS 8 (because it uses some new Core Motion APIs that only work with iOS 8). It seems like iOS7 users are still able to download my app, even though the deployment target is iOS8 and the App Store says "Compatibility: Requires iOS 7.0 or later". Can I force app to run in iOS8 only? Does the Deployment Target option in Xcode still control which version of the OS is required on the App Store?

Comment: According to this (http://stackoverflow.com/q/3559936/558933 - old but possibly relevant) you need to change the deployment target on both the project settings and the current target. Does the linked post help?

Comment: @RoboticCat beat me to it lol. But yes, setting the deployment target in both as Robotic Cat said should require iOS 8 to download. I've seen multiple apps in the App Store that require it.

Comment: Actually, you only need to set the Deployment Target on the target. The project Deployment Target just needs to be less than or equal to the desire target Deployment Target.

Comment: Ack - I set the Deployment Target for the project but not the Target itself. The Target was still iOS7. Dang now everyone using iOS7 seems to be having problems with my app crashing while I would have rather prevented them from downloading it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, you have to set the Deployment Target in three different places, in the project, in the app target, and (in my case) in the extension. If you don't set it in all three locations the app won't show as iOS 8 only.

Answer (score 2):

Deployment target on all your TARGETS is the correct option. It's important to understand the different between "Deployment target" and "Base SDK". Both regard a iOS SDK version, but they have different meanings. To learn what read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568572/whats-the-meaning-of-base-sdk-ios-deployment-target-target-and-project-in-xc).